# What do international laws say about using a software which is free only for non-commercial purposes but used otherwise?

Tags: contract-law

Concerning the question in title

> What do international laws say about using a software which is free only for non-commercial purposes?

I am talking about software which are free for students or in general for non-commercial use.
Of course I understand the meaning of such statement and I believe it's fair.

My question is basically: **what does according to International laws happen when use certain tools for professional purposes even if you have a non-professional license?**

Comment: 1) International != internal 2) Probably nothing specific, why are you interested in *international* law specifically?

Comment: you're totally right. there was a typo. it's for my personal knowledge and curiosity, since this is a common scenario : many company in the US sell software which are also being used in Australia, Europe... that's why international

Comment: You will be interested in the national laws of those countries and in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict_of_laws - the latter is a subset of international law

Answer (score 1, accepted):

International law says very little about private contracts unless there are statutes in a country where a claim could be filed that would affect the operation of the contract.

Otherwise, the usual rules of construction apply, the *usual rules* being the rules that a court with jurisdiction to hear the matter would apply.

That is:

- Software X is available free online for non-commercial (a limited licence)
- Someone uses the tools for commercial use (*professional* might be different to *commercial*, so I'll just keep this simple)
- A person with the right to enforce the licence to software X becomes aware of this and brings a claim in country Y.
- The court of country Y, if it has jurisdiction to hear the matter, constructs the meaning of the licence and considers any relevant legislation and makes a finding.